# Rotating ImageView with UIPanGestureRecognizer, ERROR-- Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to rotate an imageview with a pangesturerecognizer. Basically, I rotate the image depending on the x coordinate. I'm almost there, but I ran into a couple errors.

I set up the gesture recognizer by doing this (i have to do everything programmatically):

```
        let personDrag = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(foo.personDragRecognizer))

        rPersonImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        rPersonImageView.addGestureRecognizer(personDrag)
        self.fooVarTap6 = personDrag //the class is called foo
```

And then here is the gesture recognizer function:

```
@objc func personDragRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    guard personDrag.state == .began || personDrag.state == .changed else {
        return
    }

    guard let imgView = personDrag.view else {
        return
    }

    let translation = personDrag.translation(in: self.view)
    imgView.center = CGPoint(x: imgView.center.x + translation.x, y: imgView.center.y + translation.y)
    personDrag.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

    //originally had self before .degreesToRadians
    let angle: CGFloat = rPersonImageView.degreesToRadians(180.0)

    /* After reaching x point case - rotating and setting rotation occured to prohibit further rotation */

    if imgView.layer.frame.origin.x <= 190, currentRotation != .xPoint190 {

        imgView.transform = imgView.transform.rotated(by: angle)
        currentRotation = .xPoint190

    } else if imgView.layer.frame.origin.x >= 300, currentRotation != .xPoint300 {

        imgView.transform = imgView.transform.rotated(by: angle)
        currentRotation = .xPoint300
    }

}
```

Everywhere I mention personDrag it says "use of unresolved identifier personDrag" but I defined personDrag as you can see. It also says that "UIImageView has no member degreesToRadian" but someone else on stack said it should. Can anyone help me with this? Any help would be immensely appreciated!! Thanks a ton in advance.

Cheers,
Theo

Comment: And the compiler is correct, there is no such method as `degreesToRadian` on `UIImage`.

Comment: @rmaddy could you help me with that? is there an alternative that would function the same way?

Comment: Do a search. It's a trivial calculation and you'll find plenty of examples, even in Swift.

Comment: @rmaddy isn't the problem the object before `.degreesToRadians(180)` though? I tried view, imgView, imgView.layer, etc.

Comment: No, the problem is that there is no such method as `degreesToRadians` anywhere. You need to create your own.

Comment: ahh, gotcha. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`personDrag` is defined to be a gesture recognizer, assigned properly, and properly coded. But inside your `personDragRecognizer()` as *defined*, every reference to should be against `gestureRecognizer` instead.

The easiest fix to make things work is rename the function as:

```
func personDragRecognizer(_ personDrag UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // your code here
}
```

The other fix is to rename each and every reference inside as:

```
guard gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed else {
    return
}
```

So on and so forth.

Comment: thanks so much!! do you think you could help me with the degreesToRadians problem as well? I posted a new question about it. I'd upvote the hell out of your answer if you took the time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990248/value-of-type-uiimageview-has-no-member-degreestoradians-swift

Comment: Look into using CGAffineTransform for rotating. That's the best I can do at the moment.

Comment: I use a pan gesture for moving views and a rotate gesture for rotating - and that uses `CATransform3DRotate` and rotate both X/Y - so I'm not sure if my code will help.